# ASP.net - How to reference a text box in the code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

This is highly likely to be a stupid question, so my apologies. But I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. I am brand new to `ASP.net` and I'm using C# for the code behind (I have experience with C# from a WinForms project I did, also in Visual Studio)

I have a page, a register for an account page, on the website and I want to be able to access the `TextBox` that contains email and password etc. I thought it would be something like `textboxname.getText()` or similar to get what the user has typed into that box when they press submit (clicking submit is my `Event`) but I don't now how to make it recognize that `textboxname` is the ID.

For example:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" id="email"/>
```

My email `TextBox` has an ID of 'email'. In code, if I try to type `email.getText()`, it does not recognize that email refers to that `TextBox`. If I could even get it to recognize the ID, I could figure out the rest from there.

Thank you for listening to my excessive beginner ranting! If any extra details are necessary I'll add them, just ask.

Resolved! - For some reason it did not generate a designer for my pages when i created the web forms, so i regenerated the design.cs and it is working! :D Thanks for help anyway!

Comment: Can you show us your code? Are you using runat="server"?

Comment: yourControlId.Text gives you the text in that control

Comment: @techspider, looks like OP's problem is that `yourControlId` cannot be recognized

Comment: @Jodie - please put your HTML and backend Code to get help

Comment: You should really post code from your markup and the code behind so we can help resolve this.

Comment: Based on what you have posted, you must add runat="server" to access it from code behind.

Comment: If the problem is resolved, make sure you accept answer that helped you.

Comment: @Sravan Kumar I looked for a button to do so but I see no button to say its resolved >.< I'm likely an idiot and not seeing it by mistake or I would say resolved properly, though no answer helped me

Answer (score 1):

Be sure your markup is correct on front end - even if you are a space off between quotes it can mess things up.

```
<asp:TextBox id="email" runat="server" Text="Email" />


email.Text = "your text here";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use email.Text; (since it's a property, no a method) instead of email.getText(). Also make sure your control has runat property equals to "server" on HTML.

Answer (score 0):

## On your page

you have to declare a *form* with a *submit button* and within this form you can have your textbox.

```
<form id="myForm" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox id="TB_Email" placeholder="Enter Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Btn_Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Btn_Submit_Click" />
</form>
```

## Code behind

```
protected void Btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // here you can access the value of your email-textbox
    String email = TB_Email.Text;
}
```

Comment: It is within a form, I tried put your code in and it still did not recognise the TB_Email >.< I must have messed this up somehow

Comment: I couldn't post code because it is a uni project and I would be done for plagarism if my code was found on here. However, i got it resolved! Thanks, it was that for some reason the designer.cs files did not generate when i created the pages. So i regenerated them and it is now working! :D

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" id="email" runat="server"/>
```

or alternatively,

```
<asp:TextBox id="email" runat="server"/> /*Add any other attributes you need*/
```

In the code behind:

```
email.Text="your text here";
```

Without runat="server" attribute, your control is just a HTML control and hence you cannot access it from the server side code(code behind).